# Best way to continuously fetch MySQL data?

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I'm using right now. I fetch first query successfully, however I cannot retrieve any data from the second query. All the variables of the second query are undefined.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ended=1 ORDER BY chance ASC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$luck_steamid = $row["winner"];
$luck_total = $row["total"];
$luck_chance = $row["chance"];
$luck_round = $row["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid=".$luck_steamid;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$luck_avatar = $row["avatar"];
$luck_name = $row["name"];
$luck_profile = $row["profile"];
```

Comment: Why dont you use JOIN

Comment: Have you tried echoing your second query and running it yourself to make sure you're supposed to get back data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fetch it all at once using a join:

```
$sql = "SELECT history.winner, history.total, history.chance, history.id, users.avatar, users.name, users.profile FROM history JOIN users ON history.winner = users.steamid WHERE ended=1 ORDER BY chance ASC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$luck_steamid = $row["winner"];
$luck_total = $row["total"];
$luck_chance = $row["chance"];
$luck_round = $row["id"];
$luck_avatar = $row["avatar"];
$luck_name = $row["name"];
$luck_profile = $row["profile"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.